# execute contentscript.js.function() from injected javascript code

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-pages

i want to execute a function inside a chrome extension (type: content_page), from the injected javascript inside a webpage loaded at a tab.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

if you mean 'injected' as part of the extension then take a look at [the developer documentation for message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html).

if the injected is part of the webpage itself, or another non-extension javascript file, i don't believe there is anyway to accomplish this, or any reason it would even be safe.

if it is a function that resides at the global level, just call it as you would any other function (watch out for collisions though; if it is a common name).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what worked. And did it really amazing! "Say Thanks, Thanks, Thanks!".